# OpenCV SVM always predicts higher class label

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I'm using the OpenCV SVM implementation to binarily predict the importance of an image feature. I'm therefore training it upon positive and negative image features and looking for a classification in {0,1}.

The problem I'm encountering is that following training, the SVM always predicts the class with the higher/greater class label. I can change the labels for the training data set and this problem persists. I've carefully inspected the generated label and training cv::Mat matrices and haven't found any issues there.

Below is my SVM class and accompanying SVM parameters

```
//Populate the SVM parameters
void SVM::setSVMParams()
{
    params.svm_type = cv::SVM::C_SVC;
    params.kernel_type = cv::SVM::RBF;
    params.term_crit = cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);

    params_set = true;
}

//Train the SVM with the given data
void SVM::train(cv::Mat train_data, cv::Mat labels)
{
    //Set the SVM parameters if they haven't been already
    if (!params_set)
    {
        setSVMParams();
    }

    svm.train(train_data, labels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), params);
}

//Based on training, predict the class of the given data
float SVM::predict(cv::Mat sample)
{
    return svm.predict(sample, false);
}
```

And here is the function responsible for generating the training data and respective labels

```
//Creates the appropriate training data and class labels for subsequent SVM training according to supplied D threshold
void Matchings::createSVMTrainingObjects(const float t_D, const float positive_label, const float negative_label, bool print_info)
{
    cv::Mat train_data_l((int)matchings_list.size(), 132, CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat labels_l((int)matchings_list.size(), 1, CV_32FC1);

    int num_pos = 0;
    int num_neg = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matchings_list.size(); i++)
    {
        matching_d entry = matchings_list[i];

        //Important feature, label 1
        if (entry.D > t_D)
        {
            labels_l.at<float>(i) = positive_label;

            num_pos++;
        }
        //Unimportant feature, label -1
        else
        {
            labels_l.at<float>(i) = negative_label;

            num_neg++;
        }

        int j = 0;

        //Copy feature into current row of openCV matrix
        train_data_l.at<float>(i, j++) = entry.feature.x;
        train_data_l.at<float>(i, j++) = entry.feature.y;
        train_data_l.at<float>(i, j++) = entry.feature.scale;
        train_data_l.at<float>(i, j++) = entry.feature.angle;
        for (int k = 0; k < 128; k++)
        {
            train_data_l.at<float>(i, j + k) = entry.feature.vec[k];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "For training: #+ves=" << num_pos << ", #-ves=" << num_neg << std::endl;

    train_data = train_data_l;
    labels = labels_l;
}
```

And finally, here is the function that actually calls upon SVM prediction results for retaining important image features

```
matchingslist ASIFT::filterFeaturesWithSVM(matchingslist matchings, SVM& svm)
{
    matchingslist new_matchings;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)matchings.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::Mat first = Utility::keypointToMat(matchings[i].first);
        cv::Mat second = Utility::keypointToMat(matchings[i].second);

        //If both features are of importance, retain them
        if (svm.predict(first) == 1.0f && svm.predict(second) == 1.0f)
        {
            new_matchings.push_back(matchings[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Feature removed" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return new_matchings;
}
```

Comment: You should present minimal working example of your problem. Code that you are using, sample data. Without it noone can help - only guess.

Comment: Thanks, yes I should have done.. I've updated the question with code samples for how I'm interacting with the SVM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One main problem with the approach is that you do not set hyperparemeters of your SVM, while you use RBF, so probably `C=1` and `gamma=1/d` (or `1/mean ||x||^2`) as these are default values in most implementations of SVM.

While these are critical to build a valid model. In particular, if your `C` value is too low (`1` might be, depends on many features of data) then SVM builds a trivial model simply **always predicting one of the classes**.

What you should do? You should check multiple values of both `C` and `gamma`. What are the meanings of these parameters?

- `C` (your `1`) is a weight of missclassification - greater the `C`, SVM will try harder to learn training data exactly, possibly at the cost of overfitting.
- `gamma` (your default) is the inverse of the 2 times variance of your RBF kernel. In other words - greater the gamma, smaller the Gaussians, and thus - your method is more "local" in the geometrical sense. Again - big gamma helps you minimize the training error (bias) but leads to higher testing error (variance).

Correct selection of the tradeoff between variance-bias is crucial element of machine learning techniques. In case of RBF SVM - you can control it through the above. Play around with them, check both training set error and testing set error to see what is happening. If your training set error is big - increase C and/or gamma. Once your training set error is fine, look at the testing set - if it is too big - try to decrese values and so on. It is usually done in automatic manner through some internal cross validation with grid search of the paremeters.

Check out materials on *model selection* and *hyperparameter optimization*.

Furthermore you fix number of iterations

```
params.term_crit = cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);
```

while for SVM you should never do that. Let it converge (or at least put something like 100,000), after just 100 steps it might be the case that SVM did not come even close to convergence (thus resulted in trivial model).

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helps, I will experiment with changing C and gamma (I'm not sure what they're set to by default)

Comment: And I think the values within the termination criteria parameter don't have anything to do with C or gamma, the 100 corresponds to the maximum number of iterations and 1e-6 to the required accuracy. See here - http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#cvtermcriteria

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, it's very helpful and insightful. I just have another follow up question.. I'm not entirely sure what you mean about the training set error. Do you mean utilising the same dataset for training and for testing?

Comment: Yes, training set error is an error measured on the very same data that was used for training. If the error is high here - then for sure you **underfit**; when this is small - then it is important not to overfit (high error on test/valid data)